# Replacing double quote with single quote to store in SQLite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, xcode4.3

I would like to replace all double quotes with single quotes in a string. I have tried using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` but it does not work. How do i make it replace all the double quotes with single quotes so that i can store it into the database?

```
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithString:charDesc.text];
[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"''"];

if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK){
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE CHARACTER SET charName = \"%@\", charDescription = \"%@\" WHERE charID = %i", charName.text, charDesc.text, charID];

    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE){
        status.text = @"Succesfully Updated!";
    }else{
        status.text = @"Failed to Update!";
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(database); 
}
```

Comment: You don't.  You prepare the statement, bind the variables and insert the row.

Comment: meaning? if don't have any double quotes, i can successfully add into my database. but if i have double quotes, i won't be able to add

Comment: Yes you will.  If you bind the variable, rather than constructing the complete statement yourself, sqlite will take care of any escaping required.

Comment: sorry. but can you give me an example? thanks!

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html

Answer (score 1):

```
string=[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"'"];
```